# How can I use two iPads and one Apple ID and still have different content on each iPad

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, apple-id

I have two iPads and I've backed up and transferred everything onto the second iPad. So now they are identical in loaded apps and data. But I want to use them for different purposes, pleasure and business.

How can I delete things on only one iPad without them being deleted from the other as well.

Comment: What about things like documents and photos. Will they remain on the original iPad. And how can they both be backed up on iCloud as separate iPads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete apps on any device without affecting the other.

Comment: What about things like documents and photos. Will they remain on the original iPad. And how can they both be backed up on iCloud as separate iPads?

Comment: If you have the same AppleID then documents and photos will sync and remain the same on both, unless you sign out of iCloud on one of them and only back one up to your computer. But Matteo is essentially correct about apps, the difficulty comes with documents and pictures and how you sync them. I'd do one via iCloud and one manually and that might yield what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings → General → Reset → Erase Content and Settings. This will reset the iPad, removing all content and resetting all settings, without affecting any other iPad.

Comment: I think that the OP does not want to remove everything, but it's just my impression

Answer (score 0):

iTunes manages each device separately.  First, give the iPads different names so you can tell them apart, even though iTunes already knows.  Do this on the devices themselves.  Then, plug both in to the computer separately and you should have the devices available separately, although now iTunes shows them in this stupid device selector that barely looks like a selector at all.  It's a button that has an icon for the device and, again, with the latest screw-up of the iTunes UI you may not notice it.  Click on it and you should see two iPads in a drop-down menu.  Select the old one and select music, photos, etc to remove those ones you don't want.

I really think your problem here might be mainly due to the iTunes UI.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable iCloud on one of the iPads, meaning it won't download content from the other. 
Or effect the content of the other